# Is there an exception to the "don't edit the code logic or functionality" mantra when the code in question is something the OP claims is correct?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

I have read quite a few similar questions on meta but none that tackle this specific issue (in my mind... open to other minds disagreeing of course!). Specifically I read **[this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code)** and a bunch of other questions that were mostly marked duplicates and referenced back to the question linked above.

**Is there an exception to the "don't edit the code logic or functionality" mantra when the code in question is something that the OP claims is correct and is not a part of their question but rather a statement of (in their mind) fact which they are building off of in asking their question and looking for a solution?**

I have been wondering specifically if I did the right thing in **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27555125/accessing-changed-string-perl/27555470#27555470)**. In the example the OP says "I am perfectly aware how one is supposed to find the wanted region in the $str" but then proceeded to use substr incorrectly in demonstrating how (s)he would find the wanted region.

Since my posted answer at the time that (s)he edited his question to include that line was basically just an explanation of how to use substr to solve what I perceived as his/her full issue I felt like it could be taken the wrong way or seem like I was trying to embarrass him/her if I edited my answer to point out that (s)he was using incorrectly the function which I had explained in my answer. I was especially concerned about this perception since his/her change was very obviously made in response to my original posted answer.

Additionally, since I was also still under 50 rep I couldn't write a comment which might have been a good middle ground (ie he could do the edit him/herself). **Was editing (as I did) the right decision here and/or any other recommendations about how I could have better handled this?** I am new to stackoverflow as a contributor and want to make sure I am participating in a "correct" and constructive way :)

Comment: Editing code in *answers* is far more acceptable than editing code in *questions*. Make sure to not change the intent of course, but if its just a typo, then go ahead and fix it. You don't do that for *questions* because the typo could be the problem!

Comment: I find it a little challenging to follow exactly what the issue here is , but rest-assured you are doing just fine Lauren :-) welcome to Stack !!!!

Comment: Thanks Bradley that is the general case I agree and respect that. However, the OP in this example said that they were "perfectly aware" of how to do "Part A" and were looking for how to build off of that and complete "Part B". So "Part A" which contained an issue was not part of the question in their post. Additionally, they did not have that sentence in their post until after I posted my answer which to me said they had read and tried to incorporate what I had suggested but had not understood how to correctly use the function and *more dangerously* thought they did understand that aspect.

Comment: @coffee wondering if it was right to make the edit to their post in this case despite it going against the general case of avoiding making edits to code logic. Also thanks for the welcome :)

Comment: It's common for beginners to make incorrect assumptions in their questions. The best way to address these is in a comment or an answer, so that future visitors with the same misconceptions can learn. If I were you, after the OP edited the question, I would have edited my answer to point out the error in their logic, and possibly also added a comment on the question saying the same thing. Something like, "You seem to think that X, but that is incorrect, it's actually Y. See the latest edit of my answer for why."

Comment: Of course, the above approach is only one way to deal with [chameleon questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478). If the OP continues changing the question, you may just want to leave your answer as is and get out.

Comment: Thanks @ThisSuitIsBlackNot ...part of my dilemma was that I did not yet have comment privileges so I felt my options were limited. I think now that I have earned said privileges (yay!) going forward I will as you suggest leave a comment instead as that gives them some prompting and also the ability to fix the post themselves.

Comment: As to your second point and @coffee as well I think I was definitely also thrown off and unsure how to respond bc it seemed the question had changed in response to my answer. Thanks both for all your advice :)

Comment: If the OP's code is wrong, fix it in an answer.  If they go DERP, then delete your answer.

Comment: I had the experience as OP in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27650453/is-it-safe-to-leak-this-imageobserver-in-constructor) of realizing that my code had a flaw unrelated to the question itself (imageUpdate return value was opposite of correct), editing my question to fix it, but then having my corresponding suggested edit to the answer rejected, leaving two different versions of the code between question and answer, a possible source of confusion for viewers.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: That first comment of yours should be an answer here ;-)

Comment: @Cerbrus Added as an answer, let me know if you feel it should be expanded at all (feels a bit short to me).,

Comment: I would like to add to the answers the thought that after the problem in question has been found it should be especially easy to improve the code without editing the problem out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that the *"don't edit the code logic or functionality"* should be taken more like a guideline than a rule. The purpose of it is clear and really important as a general principle. As with this kind of guideline usually, it should only be treated as a guideline, and if you can find a good reason to not to follow it that you can justify to yourself, go for it. The guideline has then done it's job as you have considered it as it should be considered and still you think it is reasonable.

Another thing is the fact that edits are peer reviewed until you have 2k of reputation. If you can't justify the need for the edit for others, it probably isn't making that much sense (assuming that the reviewers aren't following this mantra blindly) and shouldn't be approved. Anyway, you don't need to worry it all by yourself, peer review makes sure of that.

Comment: _"Another thing is the fact that edits are peer reviewed."_ Not when you have 2k rep.

Comment: Good point, so used to that (since I don't have 2k) that didn't even consider that.

Comment: @Cerbrus But I believe the author of the post always gets a notification when an edit is made? So he or she can still review those.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: That's correct, yes.

Comment: And even "peer review" is tainted by robo-reviewers, so you *still* need to make sure the edit is good.

Comment: I think in my particular case (if I had the rep at the time) leaving a comment about the fix would have been the best answer. However, since I didn't, and since I like that this answer is getting at the more general question behind my specific example I have accepted it.

Answer (score 9):

Normally, relevant problems with the question's code should be pointed out in an answer, not by editing the question.

If the OP explicitly claims that something is correct, even though it isn't, this discrepancy sounds very relevant to the question and shouldn't just be removed without a hint what happened. After all, the purpose of keeping a solved question-answer pair is usefulness to future readers: what went wrong, and how was the problem solved? This should contain the actual misunderstandings that led to the question. Substantial edits about this should be done by the post's author, who really knows what it was about.

I think "embarrassing the author" should be less important than clearly identifying the problem(s) and the solution. Mistakes happen, we shouldn't let that get in the way of the answering process. Whether authors are uncomfortable with the way a question reflects on them personally is for them to decide. If they choose to leave the question as is, I'd say the mistake is a part of it and belongs there.

Comment: Or in a comment.

Comment: It *can* be relevant to the question. Sometimes. Or it's a completely irrelevant sideshow, and should have been corrected in the question immediately.

Answer (score 5):

It depends.

Editing code in *answers* is far more acceptable than editing code in *questions*. Make sure to not change the intent of course, but if its just a typo, then go ahead and fix it.

You don't do that, **ever**, for questions because the typo could be the problem! Feel free to leave a comment in such cases (when you have the reputation).

Answer (score 3):

I am a complete novice when it comes to programming. Not only am I struggling with syntax, I also am struggling with the logic.
That said, if a question I post would get edited in such a way that it changed my code in the question, I doubt that I would be able to quickly identify the correction - or find it at all.
Not only are there experts on here, but novices who are just trying to learn this stuff for personal amusement and not for profit or gain. I hope I can speak for all of us "noobs", that we appreciate you guys and gals taking the time to share your knowledge, to point out that we didn't close a `<div>` or forgot to end with a `;`. However if that is not explicitly pointed out to us, we may never realize what the answer is.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, it depends. In this case I support your edit because it was (a) not part of the actual question itself, but a tangential observation, (b) wrong without breaking the rest of the post, (c) trivially correctable.

BTW didn't spot and correct the missing `)` character :P

Comment: haha funny you mention that bc I actually did notice that missing ")" in the text of their question but only AFTER I had submitted my edit and it really did irrationally bother me lol but just *barely* not enough to go find 5 other characters to change!